# Check or nickname already exists in List<User>

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I am creating an ASP website with a possibility to register.

The nickname that visitors choose to register has to be unique.

Everytime when an user registers, I select all users from the database, and then I am using a foreach loop to check or username already exists:

```
private List<User> listExistingUsers;
listExistingUsers = Database.GetUsers();
foreach (User u in listExistingUsers)
{
    if (u.Nickname == txtNickname.text)
    {
        Error = "Username already in use.";
    }
}
```

But the code above doesn't work properly. It doesn't check all the items in the list which are read from the database. So it is possible to have users with the same usernames, which I don't want.

What can I do to solve this problem? I read about LINQ, but I think that this is the wrong way of checking usernames with List<> in my opinion. I think this username-check must be done in another way.

Can you experts help me? I could also do this check with a SQL-query, but I would like to do it in c#.

Comment: What do you mean that it doesn't check all of the items in the list that are read from the database? What line is breaking out of the `foreach` loop? are you sure that `listExistingUsers` contains all the users?

Comment: just a thought, but it may be case issue. try `if (u.Nickname.ToLower() == txtNickname.text.ToLower())` before proceeding to the solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of returning ALL users from DB, pass username to Query/stored procedure and let backend do the check, and then return back just a status flag 1/0 - exists/doesn't.

Comment: You mean I need to do something like this?:
public List<User> CheckUsername(string username)
{
    string sql = "SELECT Username FROM User WHERE Username = @username"
}

Comment: and if that list returns .Count > 1 then the username exists?

Comment: @xVizzi that's one way of doing it. You don't even have to select username and check for count, just `SELECT 1` and check result for DbNull

Comment: Something like `If (dbComm.ExecuteScalar("SELECT Username FROM User WHERE Username = @username") == DbNull.Value) Error = "Username already in use.";`

Comment: Sorry that should be `!= DbNull.Value`

Comment: Well u got the idea :) Please let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: Tried this: http://pastebin.com/VxKyDphJ
But doesn't work :( Keeps saying that username exists.

Comment: Can you assign result of `command.ExecuteScalar()` to an Object variable and in debug see what is the value of that result?

Comment: Exactly but I wanted to know what `test` is equal to. I think `ExecuteScalar()` may return `null` for nonexisting data, if that's the case instead of comparing to `!= DBNull.Value` you will have to compare to `!= null`

Comment: I guess that is the specifics of ExecuteScalar - if underlying query returns no data - it present it as null.

Answer (score 4):

`if (Database.GetUsers().Select(x => x.Nickname).Contains(txtNickname.Text))` should do what you want.

I've condensed everything into a single line so I'll give a quick explanation; First I use your `Database.GetUsers()` method to retrieve the users, then I use select to project the Nickname since that's what we're comparing. If that were to execute on it's own it would result in an `IEnumerable<string>` with all of the Nicknames. From there I use contains to see if that list contains the nickname that (I'm assuming) has been entered in the UI.

Comment: Thank you. Is this the best way to do this check you think?

Comment: @xVizzi in C# code, it is. If you don't actually need the users then you're probably better off just doing the check in SQL. Also, I'm if you're going to use the users elsewhere then you should assign the return value of `Database.GetUsers()` to a local var on a line above this so you don't have to repeat that query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Contains operator` in order tocheck

```
listExistingUsers.Select(x => x.Nickname).Contains(txtNickname.text);
```

link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bhkz42b3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Remark : You can use `Any` or `count` (very expensive last solution)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) operator. It checks whether any element of a sequence satisfies some condition. In your case condition is *user nickname equals to text in textBox*:

```
if (Database.GetUsers().Any(u => u.Nickname == txtNickname.Text))
    Error = "Username already in use.";
```

BTW if you change `GetUsers` to return `IQueryable<User>` then check will occur on server side.

Answer (score 1):

Do get a list of NickNames once

```
var nickNames = new List<string>();

for(int i=0;i<listExistingUsers.Count;i++)
{
     nickNames.Add(listExistingUsers.NickName);
}
```

Then u can simply use

```
if(nickNames.Contains(txtNickname.text))
{
     Error = "Username already in use.";
}
```

Comment: listExistingUsers is list of user,you must select user name

Answer (score 0):

1) Have you verified that Database.GetUsers() is actually returning the full list, with no SQL issues?

2) Do you need it to be case-insensitive?

3) You can use the LINQ to do the query like this:

```
if (listExistingUsers.Any(u => string.Equals(u, txtNickname.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)))
{
   // Process error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If Database.GetUsers() return all the users from database, so **do not** use it! Imagine if you have already 1000 of users, for each new user it will load all the users, and you will have performance issues.

Instead, create a new method that search your database and return only **one** result, case it exists.
Something like :

```
private bool Database.UserExists(txtNickname.text) {
      //Your query to database with a where statment looking for the nickname. It could be a LINQ query, or any other way you use in your system.
      //If it brings 1 result, it has to return true. 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**I think the most tricky part of your task is to fill the database Correctly.**

Particularly:

- Cut off trailing and ending spaces
- Decide if the user names should becase sensitive
- Make sure that when creating a new user name you do not have the nick already

**About Loading users and checking:**

As mentioned above LINQ is the most effective a C# like checking for duplicates
( if (Database.GetUsers().Select(x => x.Nickname).Contains(txtNickname.Text)))

I am more used to writing SQL statements than using LINQ. If you've got lots of users SQL will read only the selected ones but I don't know if the LINQ statement above pulls all users into the memory pool or just the one(s) with the same nickname.